# List unique result only on history command

Tags: 14.04, grep, history, sort

I ran this command

`history | cut -c 8-`

It listed all the history commands as expected without line numbers.

I'm wondering if there is a way to list only unique one.

I've tried

`history | cut -c 8- | sort -u`

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unique in what respect?

Comment: Trying to avoid seeing same commands in history. I’m trying to documents what I did for the pass months and see a lot of commands is confusing

Answer (score 2):

To get the names of the commands only, you can use this:

```
history | cut -f4 -d\  | sort -u
```

Or for better results, you can use this:

```
history | sort -u -b -k2,2
```

Comment: That command showed a lot of number

Comment: @kyo : Can you try `history | sort -u -b -k2,2` ?

Comment: that seems working fine.